# Dynamically set primary and foreign keys in reflected tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am writing an utility which would reflect a large chunk of database based on a list of tables (around 70-100 tables, almost 5000 unique columns). In a second step it would take a list of columns, create a large multi-table join and construct a select statement with the join statement correctly assembled according to primary and foreign keys. The select statement string or the joined object itself would then be passed to Pandas which would process the database query. The issue comes in the joining part.

Some parts of the database are badly governed and don't contain any PK or FK constraints (a product of many people working on many source systems). The tables of concern are luckily derived from the governed part of the database and informally contain some aspects of integrity. PK/FK columns (mostly customer_id, validity_dt) come from 'good' tables, but sometimes are named haphazardly - cid/id_cust/... dat_validity/val_dt/... (Already solved, but needs to be mentioned).

As there is a large varying number of tables to be joined handpicking columns in the join statement is not an option. I would like to rely on built-in property of SQLA which builds a correct join statement automatically based on PK/FKs. I would like to enforce the keys on every reflected table inside metadata object. The resulting select statement object/string is a sufficient end product as I don't want to push the changes to the DB (I don't have write access to some tables).

For testing purposes I assigned two tables out of the metadata_obj and tried something like the following examples. The assignment works but joining the tables fails:

```py
secondary_table.foreign_keys = set([ForeignKey(primary_table.c.get('customer_id')),\
ForeignKey(primary_table.c.get('validity_dt'))])
joined = primary_table.join(secondary_table)
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_creation_order'`

or

```py
secondary_table.foreign_keys = ForeignKeyConstraint(['cid', 'dat_validity'],\
['primary_table.customer_id', 'primary_table.validity_dt'])
joined = primary_table.join(secondary_table)
```

`NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'primary_table' and 'secondary_table'.`

Is this achievable without ORM and dynamically? List of tables changes according to the needs on Python side and some might be added/removed on DB side later.

Info: I am using SQLA 2.0.22 with Oracle 19c.